# Finding the basis for a sum of vector spaces when we know the basis for each.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am stuck trying to work out this proof :

**Statement:** If $P$ is a basis for the set $A\cap B$ and we extend it to $Q$ - a basis of $A$ and $R$ - a basis of B. Then $R\cup Q$ is a basis for $A+B$.

**My Approach towards a proof:**
Let $$P=(p_1,p_2....p_n)$$ is the basis for $A\cap B$

Now I extend it to a basis of A as: $$Q=(p_1,p_2....p_n,q_1,q_2....q_s)\;\;\;\;\;\;q_i\epsilon A-B$$
And to a basis of B as:$$R=(p_1,p_2....p_n,r_1,r_2....r_t)\;\;\;\;\;\;r_i\epsilon B-A$$

Thus we get $$P\cup Q=\{p_1,...p_n,q_1....q_s,r_1....r_t\}$$
All we need to do is show that $PUQ$ spans $A+B$ and that it is a linearly independant set.
Now as $P$ was a basis for $A$ we can write any arbitrary element of $A$ as : $$a=\sum\alpha_{i}p_{i}+\sum\beta_{j}q_{j}$$
similarly we can write $$b=\sum\alpha'_{i}p_{i}+\sum\gamma_{j}r_{j}$$

Now we can just algebriacally add the two expressions to get $$a+b=\sum(\alpha_{i}+\alpha'_{i})p_{i}+\sum\beta_{j}q_{j}+\sum\gamma_{j'}r_{j'}$$
which is nothing but by definition - an arbitrary element of $A+B$ which has successfully been expressed as a linear combination of the elements of $P\cup Q$. Thus $A+B \subseteq$ $Span(R\cup  Q)$. We can also trivially show that $Span(R\cup Q) \subseteq A+B$. Thus we can finally say that:

$$Span(R\cup Q)=A+B$$

*But I have no idea how to prove that the elements of $P\cup Q$ are Linearly Independent*

Comment: Do you mean to say that $Q \cup R$ is a basis for $A+B$?

Comment: $P\cup Q=Q$ and this is a basis for $A$, not for $A+B$. Please read the question and make necessary corrections.

Comment: @innerproduct yes that is what i mean... i will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ If $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ spans the vector space $V$ and $\dim(V)=n$, then $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ is a basis for $V$.